# Protractor execute non-test action in the end of the test scenario

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, protractor, automated-tests

I'm writing my first Protractor test scenario and I'm discovering the mysterious world of promises. But I really can't understand one thing. Here is how my test looks like:

```
let stuff = "Some data I pick up from a CSV file"

describe("Foo", function () {

  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) // maybe not a relevant piece of information to share but how knows

  for (let i of testdata) {
    it("Bar", function () {
      browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
      browser.get(browser.baseUrl)
      doStuff1()
      let usefulCalculatedData = doStuff2(stuff)
      doStuff3()
      storeThisStuffInACSVFile(usefulCalculatedData);
    })
  }

})

function doStuff2(stuff){
  var today = new Date()
  let usefulCalculatedData = today.getFullYear().toString()
  + today.getMonth() + 1
  + today.getDate()
  + today.getHours()
  + stuff
  doActualStuff(usefulCalculatedData)
  return usefulCalculatedData
}
```

I'm expecting the step "storeThisStuffInACSVFile" to be run in the end of the `it`. But actually, it is run at the very beginning of the test! Which means that some part of `doStuff2()` is called... By the way, all the test executes very well. I'm just really confused because I don't know how to force the order I want.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: look up how to handle promises, this is your problem

Comment: and if I understand your problem correctly, noone can help you given only the code you posted. then underlying problem is within `doActualStuff` `doStuff1` and `doStuff3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution combining async/await & promises. I don't know if it's very standard but... it works...

```
let stuff = "Some data I pick up from a CSV file"

describe("Foo", function () {

  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) // maybe not a relevant piece of information to share but how knows

  for (let i of testdata) {
    it("Bar", function () {
      browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
      browser.get(browser.baseUrl)
      doStuff1()
      let usefulCalculatedData = doStuff2(stuff)
      // EDITED HERE
      doStuff3().then(function()
        {storeThisStuffInACSVFile(usefulCalculatedData);
      });
    })
  }

})

function doStuff2(stuff){
  var today = new Date()
  let usefulCalculatedData = today.getFullYear().toString()
  + today.getMonth() + 1
  + today.getDate()
  + today.getHours()
  + stuff
  doActualStuff(usefulCalculatedData)
  return usefulCalculatedData
}

// EDITED HERE
async function doStuff3(){
  var whateverOutput = await whatever()
  return Promis.resolve(usefulCalculatedData !== null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilise the power of await:

```
let stuff = "Some data I pick up from a CSV file"

describe("Foo", function () {

  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) // maybe not a relevant piece of information to share but how knows

  for (let i of testdata) {
    it("Bar", async function () {
      await browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
      await browser.get(browser.baseUrl)
      doStuff1()
      let usefulCalculatedData = doStuff2(stuff)
      doStuff3()
      storeThisStuffInACSVFile(usefulCalculatedData);
    })
  }

})

function doStuff2(stuff){
  var today = new Date()
  let usefulCalculatedData = today.getFullYear().toString()
  + today.getMonth() + 1
  + today.getDate()
  + today.getHours()
  + stuff
  doActualStuff(usefulCalculatedData)
  return usefulCalculatedData
}
```

Make sure you disable selenium promise in config file:

```
exports.config = {
 
  ...
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  ...
 
};
```

Now you don't have to do promise chaining instead use await, in protractor every proser function is a promise.